# How to implement Evented IO for C libraries (NCurses specifically)

Tags: crystal-lang

When using the standard input methods, (`gets`,) processing time is given to other fibers. So the following works correctly:

```
spawn do
  puts "Hello!"
end

gets

# This will output Hello! unless input was already buffered
```

But when using C libraries to read input/events, processing time is not given to the fiber. The easiest example to show might be SDL as there are [bindings](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/tree/master/samples/sdl) in the samples.

```
# Adapted from samples/sdl/fire.cr
require "./sdl/sdl"

SDL.init
SDL.set_video_mode 100, 100, 32, LibSDL::DOUBLEBUF

spawn do
  puts "Hello!" # This will never run unless sleep or something built-in is used
end

loop do
  SDL.poll_events do |event|
    case event.type
    when LibSDL::QUIT
      SDL.quit
      exit
    when LibSDL::KEYDOWN
      case event.key.key_sym.sym
      when LibSDL::Key::ESCAPE, LibSDL::Key::Q
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This shows the issue, but the problem I want to solve is actually with my [NCurses](https://github.com/SamualLB/ncurses) and [Termbox](https://github.com/SamualLB/lib_termbox) bindings.

```
# NCurses non-working example
require "ncurses"

NCurses.start

spawn do
  NCurses.add_char 110_u8, 0, 0
  NCurses.refresh
end

NCurses.get_char # This blocks, but does not allow fibers to be processed

NCurses.end
```

```
# Termbox non-working example
require "lib_termbox"

LibTermbox.init

spawn do
  LibTermbox.change_cell 0, 0, 110_u32, 0_u16, 0_u16
  LibTermbox.present
end

LibTermbox.poll_event(out event) # Again this is blocking but the fiber does not run

LibTermbox.shutdown
```

I have tried reading through the source code how evented IO works, but I do not really understand it or how to re-implement it.

The best workaround I have seen so far would be just to rewrite the input functions, (such as the [2048 sample](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/master/samples/2048.cr#L39))

```
# Example input

spawn do
  puts "Hello!" # this works unless input is buffered already
end

STDIN.raw do |io|
  buffer = Bytes.new(4)
  bytes_read = io.read(buffer)
  pp String.new(buffer[0, bytes_read]) # Display some sort of grapheme cluster?
end
```

Comment: What happens if you compile it with -Dpreview_mt?

Comment: I should have added that! I thought multi threading was enabled by default now  but I guess not. This is definitely a good workaround.